Alphabetically in the middle
Prompt will ask for 3 input letters, can be lower and upper cases, how do I print out the alphabetically middle one only?
Outcome should be something like this:
1st letter: x
2nd letter: c
3rd letter: p
The letter in the middle is p

The solution, preferably, should be with if/elif/else statements, comparison operators mainly.
I tried this:
first = input('1st letter: ')
second = input('2nd letter: ')
third = input('3rd letter: ')

if first.upper() < second.upper() and second.upper() < third.upper():
    print(f"The letter in the middle is {second}")
elif second.upper() < first.upper() and first.upper() < third.upper():
    print(f"The letter in the middle is {first}")
elif third.upper() > second.upper() and third.upper() > first.upper():
    print(f"The letter in the middle is {first}")


What it gives your solution (hints: you may need to ad some text on each print, to check which cases you are testing). And then try with all possible orders, to see what case you got wrong, and then try to see the problem. Else you should be smarter programmer (but so without if/else). With if/else really you should try and debug all combinations

Put the letters in a list. Sort the list. The second element will be the middle.

Can be as simple as sorted((first, second,third))[1]. If this does not make sense, perhaps do a bit (more) research on sorting in Python, and indexing.

Your code is barely an attempt, given that it will obviously never output the third letter.

@ravshanbek-ortikov, should the code work for any language, or is it an English only solution that is required?

@Andj i chose a tag "python" and i thought it will suffice

For instance should it work for character outside basic Latin and if so which would you expect as middle character with 'a, z, ß' or better yet what should be the middle character with 'ß, Z, z'? You'll get different answers with different solutions.

Also, should 'a, z, Z' and 'a, Z, z' give the same results?

@Andj regarding should it work on characters outside the basic latin or not, idk cuz i am not quite familiar with what encoding standards (ASCII or Unicode or any others if there are any) Python checks the value of given data. But i assume, it should give different answers based on the same logic depending on the inputs, as you said, if i got you correctly. if python checks the data from unicode by default, i assume the table of unicode is much bigger than ascii table and there should enough space for even ancient greek characters

@RavshanbekOrtikov by default python compares characters based on Unicode codepoints, while Unicode itself compares based on collation weights. So different approaches.

To make this robust you should check that each input is a single character and that all input values are unique
So let's assume you've done that and you have first, second and third then...
all_inputs = {
    first.upper(): first,
    second.upper(): second,
    third.upper(): third
}

mid = sorted(all_inputs.keys())[1]

print(f"The letter in the middle is {all_inputs[mid]}")

A more comprehensive solution that does away with the unqiue constraint could be:
BEL = "\a"

def getchar(n):
    prompts = [
        "1st",
        "2nd",
        "3rd"
    ]
    while True:
        c = input(f"{prompts[n]} letter: ")
        if len(c) == 1:
            return c
        print(BEL, end="")

all_inputs = []

for i in range(3):
    c = getchar(i)
    all_inputs.append(c)

mid = sorted(all_inputs, key=str.upper)[1]

print(f"The letter in the middle is {mid}")


@s3dev The reason is that in the OP the order is based on the uppercase version of the input but the output is the original value. Therefore if the inputs are "a","b"&"c" you need to output "b" and not "B"

Thank you for detailed explanation. I used the upper snippet, it passed the task smoothly

letter1 = input("1st letter: ")
letter2 = input("2nd letter: ")
letter3 = input("3rd letter: ")
if letter1 > letter2 and letter1 > letter3:
if letter2 > letter3:

    middle = letter2

else:

    middle = letter3

elif letter2 > letter3:
if letter3 > letter1:

    middle = letter3

else:

    middle = letter1

else:
if letter2 > letter1:

    middle = letter2

else:

    middle = letter1

print("The letter in the middle is " + middle)

this was the model solution from the course

So given the letters 'a', 'Z' and 'z' the expected answer 'a'?  At least that is what the model answer would give.

@Andj i didnt test the model answer, but as per what i know so far and im only few days into python and not much longer into programming or CS, from 'a', 'Z' and 'z' inputs, mid one should be 'a'. So if the model answer chooses 'a' as mid one than it working okay, i guess?

@RavshanbekOrtikov Surely, if the inputs are 'a', 'Z' and 'z' and you're comparing them in terms of their uppercase values then the middle value must be 'Z' because the sequence is, effectively, 'AZZ'

@SIGHUP of you do casing before comparison, then yes Z is middle, but if you do casing during comparison, i.e via sort key or other mechanism, then relative order in input sequence is significant.

# Input the three letters
first = input('1st letter: ')
second = input('2nd letter: ')
third = input('3rd letter: ')

# Convert letters to uppercase for case-insensitive comparison
letters = [first.lower(), second.lower(), third.lower()]

# Sort the list
letters.sort()

# The middle letter is the second element in the sorted list
middle = letters[1]

# Print the result
print(f"The letter in the middle is {middle}")

